# Adding something to a list of dates in a column

Tags: r

Supppose a data.table is:

```
dt <- structure(list(type = c("A", "B", "C"), dates = c("21-07-2011", 
    "22-11-2011,01-12-2011", "07-08-2012,14-08-2012,18-08-2012,11-10-2012"
    )), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Check it:

```
   type                                       dates
1:    A                                  21-07-2011
2:    B                       22-11-2011,01-12-2011
3:    C 07-08-2012,14-08-2012,18-08-2012,11-10-2012
```

I need to add, say, 5 to each of the dates in second column, ie, I want the result to be as under:

```
   type                                       dates
1:    A                                  26-07-2011
2:    B                       27-11-2011,06-12-2011
3:    C 12-08-2012,19-08-2012,23-08-2012,16-10-2012
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you had 1 date per row you could use `as.date` to transform into numeri and then add 5.

Comment: First step: Create some [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) instead of the useless data format you have now.

Comment: @user2974951: In an ideal world I'd have already done that.

Comment: @Roland: This is not something I have created but what I've got from an organization. The actual list contains thousands of rows and more than hundred columns. And some cells contains more than thirty dates! I know it's crazy to store this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouped by 'type',  we split the 'dates' by the `,`, (with `strsplit`), convert to a `Date` class object with `dmy` (from `lubridate`), add `5`, `format` it to the original format of the data, `paste` it to single string and assign (`:=`) to update the 'dates' column in the dataset

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
dt[, dates := paste(format(dmy(unlist(strsplit(dates, ","))) + 5, 
        '%d-%m-%Y'), collapse=','), by = type]
dt
#   type                                      dates
#1:    A                                  26-07-2011
#2:    B                       27-11-2011,06-12-2011
#3:    C 12-08-2012,19-08-2012,23-08-2012,16-10-2012
```

---

Another option without splitting, converting to `Date`, reformatting is regex method with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
dt[, dates := gsubfn("^(\\d+)", ~ as.numeric(x) + 5, 
     gsubfn(",(\\d+)", ~sprintf(",%02d", as.numeric(x) + 5), dates))]
dt
#   type                                       dates
#1:    A                                  26-07-2011
#2:    B                       27-11-2011,06-12-2011
#3:    C 12-08-2012,19-08-2012,23-08-2012,16-10-2012
```

NOTE: Would assume the second method to be faster as we are not `split`ting, converting, `paste`ing etc.

Comment: `gsubfn` package looks very useful. I also prefer second solution. Thanks. The first solution - it seems that we would need an anchor column with unique values for grouping `by=` to be effective. Do I need to create an id column with unique values if I have no such column in the original table?

Comment: @San You don't need to create new column.  It is just because we are splitting that there needs to be some identifier while `paste`ing togher.  One option is to use `by = seq_len(nrow(dt))`

Answer (score 3):

Using only basic R you can do:

```
dt$dates = sapply(dt$dates, function(x){
  dates = as.Date(strsplit(x,",")[[1]], format = "%d-%m-%Y")
  paste(format(dates+5, '%d-%m-%Y'), collapse = ",")
})
```

Result:

```
> dt
   type                                       dates
1:    A                                  26-07-2011
2:    B                       27-11-2011,06-12-2011
3:    C 12-08-2012,19-08-2012,23-08-2012,16-10-2012
```

This procedure is practically the same as the one given by akrun, but without the extra libraries.